# QGIS 2.6.1: "no enhancement" option not working on DEMs

Tags: qgis, raster, dem

When I import DEM raster layers and try to change the contrast to "no enhancement" I get a blank white image in the map window. Changing "black to white" to "white to black", the map remains a blank white image.

I want to import DEMs without stretching the histogram at all as some of them may be 8-bit images.

How can I get an un-stretched image in the map window?

Comment: How many bands has your raster? Is there any kind of colour interpretation stored in the file metadata?

Comment: It's a single band grayscale DEM. 16-bit but sometimes 8-bit. Very very dark- you know what they look like. They will export as unchanged, but I was hoping that the map window could display them without any "stretching" of the levels.

Answer (score 1):

"No enhancement" means that the colour range is from 0 to infinity (or 32768, depending on the datatype).

QGIS usually scales between 2% and 98%, which might lead to an almost unicoloured rendering, when your data is within the first 2%.